# Youtube Fullscreen Button not showing up using cloaking

Tags: javascript, youtube, youtube-api, fullscreen

My problem is that if you access to the webpage using this link :

```
http://www.animevid.net/player/?anime=d/dmc
```

The fullscreen button will show up properly, but if you access from this link :

```
http://animevid.it/     (entra nel sito > a-z > d > devil may cry)
```

Please note that animevid.it is a domain using cloaking, I really don't know if this could matter but i guess it's the problem. Also I'm using [html5box](http://html5box.com/html5gallery/)'s gallery plugin to display these videos, I've tried to edit the js that manage 'em, tried to include the allowfullscreen parameter directly to the video urls but nothing changed, hope you can give me some tips.
Edit : Looks like the problem is that using cloaking you don't give permission to go fulscreen from the "animevid.it" url, while, using "www.animevid.net" since it's not cloaked and isn't contained in a iframe, it's abled to go fullscreen and show the relative button. Reached this theory by testing with cloaking and iframing. Still need help on ho to allow fulscreen on a cloaked page.